# Модуль smsactivateru. Ошибка: activation.was_sent().request(wrapper) AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, api, requests, sms

Вот код:

```
import smsactivateru
from smsactivateru import Sms, SmsTypes, SmsService, GetBalance, GetFreeSlots, GetNumber
api = 'мой апи'
wrapper = Sms(api)


balance = GetBalance().request(wrapper)

print('На счету {} руб.'.format(balance))

activation = GetNumber(
    service=SmsService().Gmail,
).request(wrapper)
print("+"+str(activation.phone_number))

t.sleep(3)
pyautogui.sleep(3)
###Здесь  я уже номер ввёл и код отправил
activation.was_sent().request(wrapper)
code = activation.wait_code(wrapper=wrapper)
print(str(code))
```

Вот вывод:

```
На счету 50.0 руб.
+601133138466
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\AI mouse\auto\google.py", line 20, in <module>
    activation.was_sent().request(wrapper)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score 0):

Я всё сам понял. Вот так всё работает:

```
import smsactivateru
from smsactivateru import Sms, SmsTypes, SmsService, GetBalance, GetFreeSlots, GetNumber
api = 'мой апи' 

wrapper = Sms(api)

balance = GetBalance().request(wrapper)

print('На счету {} руб.'.format(balance))

activation = GetNumber(
    service=SmsService().Gmail,
    country=SmsTypes.Country.MY
).request(wrapper)

print('id: {} phone: {}'.format(str(activation.id), str(activation.phone_number)))

phoneInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="phoneNumberId"]')

phoneInput.send_keys("+"+str(activation.phone_number))

print("+"+str(activation.phone_number))

activation.was_sent()
    code = activation.wait_code(wrapper=wrapper)
    print(str(code))
```